# Create a custom resource webservice PrestaShop

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I create a module for PrestaShop 1.6 where I create a table as following in **mymodule/mymodule.php**:

```
class Mymodule extends Module {

    // Some code

    public function installDb() {
        return Db::getInstance()->execute("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "mytable`(
        `id_mdm` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `id_category` INT NOT NULL,
        `service` INT NOT NULL,
        `title` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL default '',
        `title_font_size` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL default '',
        `title_color` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL default '',
        `background_color` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL default '',
        `border_style` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL default '',
        `position` INT NOT NULL,
        `count` INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_mdm`), UNIQUE (`id_category`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");
    }

    // Some code

}
```

It works fine, my table is created. Then I override webservice in **mymodule/override/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php**:

```
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
    public static function getResources() {
        $resources = parent::getResources();
        $resources['myresource'] = array(
            'description' => '',
            'class' => 'myresource'
        );
        ksort($resources);
        return $resources;
    }
}
```

I create a new class called myresource in **mymodule/override/classes/Myresource.php**:

```
class MyresourceCore extends ObjectModel {
    public $id;
    public $id_mdm;
    public $id_category;
    public $service;
    public $title;
    public $title_font_size;
    public $title_color;
    public $background_color;
    public $border_style;
    public $position;
    public $count;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'mytable',
        'primary' => 'id_mdm',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_category' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'service' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'title' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'title_font_size' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'title_color' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'background_color' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'border_style' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'position' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'count' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT)
        )
    );

    protected $webserviceParameters = array();
}
```

In the Back office I generate a key for **myresource**, but when I test in my browser **http://mydomain/api/myresource?ws_key=mykey**, there is the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'myresource' not found in /path/mydomain/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php on line 502
```

I don't know why PrestaShop doesn't detect it. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the module after you created the override so the override is copied to the override/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php? Also check the if your override is the path for the class in cache/class_index.php. The WebserviceRequest should have the path as override/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php. You can also delete this file to recreate it.

Comment: Yes I tried reinstalling it, but nothing changes. **WebserviceRequest.php** is effectively copied to **override/classes/webservice/**. I also delete **cache/class_index.php** to trigger the regeneration but it doesn't detect **override/classes/Myresource.php**

Comment: try changing MyresourceCore to Myresource. then recrete the class_index.php.

Comment: I tried it, reinstalled and then delete class_index.php, but there is no change...

Comment: Custom classes are not autoloaded. You need to `include` your `Myresource.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an alternative solution without using the native PrestaShop webservice. I created a directory called webservice in **mymodule/webservice/mymodule.php**. This file will be used to post data to PrestaShop's website. Here is how I did it:

```
<?php
$currentDirectory = str_replace('modules/mymodule/webservice/', '', 
dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . "/");
$sep = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require_once $currentDirectory . 'config' . $sep . 'config.inc.php';
require_once $currentDirectory . 'init.php';

$hostnameIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($hostnameIp == 'AUTHORIZED_IP') {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // Some code
        http_response_code(200);
    } else {
        http_response_code(405);
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
}
```

Then I just need to execute a POST request to **myresource** at the following url: **http://mydomain/modules/mymodule/webservice/mymodule.php**.
Be careful to do some validation for security, like IP address. If the validation is successful, then your do some treatment to insert or update data to mysql tables.

Answer (score 3):

In Prestashop 1.7, you can use this hook: `addWebserviceResources`

Example:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/Sample.php';

class myAPISample extends Module {

    // ...

    public function install() {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('addWebserviceResources');
    }

    // ...

    public function hookAddWebserviceResources($params) {
         return [ 'samples' => ['description' => 'My sample', 'class' => 'Sample' ] ];
    }

    //...
}
```

See also (in french) : https://www.h-hennes.fr/blog/2018/06/25/prestashop-ajouter-un-objet-dans-lapi/

Answer (score 1):

If you check the PHP error logs, you will notice an error of the type Class not found. In this case it's class "MyResource" not found.

In order to solve this, you need to include your Model class in the constructor of the override method like this

```
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
    public function __construct()
    {
         include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'myresource' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MyResource.php');
    }

    public static function getResources()
    {
        $resources = parent::getResources();
        $resources['myresource'] = array(
            'description' => '',
            'class' => 'myresource'
        );
        ksort($resources);
        return $resources;
    }
}
```

And you need to place the Model Class in **/mymodule/classes/MyResource.php**

Placing the Model Class in **mymodule/override/classes/Myresource.php** is not correct cause there is no Myresource class to override. This will give you an error when uninstalling the module - you will not be able to uninstall it